# how to check what version of bfd I am using?

Tags: linux, gcc

I have encountered a bug when running the `gcc` command on a Linux machine, and on Googling the bug I found that people say, it has been fixed in a newer revision of the `bfd` library.  Searching further, I discovered, that `bfd` may be a static library with which `gcc` was linked when it was built, not a shared dynamic library, but I am not sure of that.

How to find out, whether the `gcc` version I have is using `bfd` statically or dynamically and what version of `bfd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BFD is the library used by programs that make up GNU's Binutils, which include `ld`, `gold`, and `as`, among others. They usually come in a package called *binutils* and *binutils-dev* (Debian and friends) or *binutils-devel* (Fedora/RHEL). You can run any of the aforementioned programs with a `-V` switch to get its version number. You can use `readelf` to list their dependencies. To list the dependencies of `ld` including their types:

```
readelf -d `which ld`

Dynamic section at offset 0xc900c contains 28 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libbfd-2.22-system.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libz.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

I am not very familiar with GCC's inner workings, but I would say it is weird to think that GCC is ever linked against BFD.

Comment: well, you say `ld` uses BFD, but, isn't `ld` part of `gcc`, in the sense that `gcc foobar.o -o foobar` is `ld`

Comment: `gcc` uses `ld` for linking, yes. But that's very different from saying `gcc` is linked against BFD (what you wrote in your post).

Comment: Correct.  I precisely wanted to know what version of BFD is my `gcc` linked against.  You seemed to be saying, that `ld` is linked against BFD, but `gcc` is not.  How can that be, when `gcc` in fact uses `ld`.

Comment: @user322908: because `gcc` is not `ld`, because `gcc` does not need any of the functions provided by BFD. You're straying from the original question.